# How can I install the new Cantarell fonts available in Gnome 3.28 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, fonts, 18.04

The Gnome 3.28 release notes say that the Cantarell font has undergone a significant update, but this font is not preinstalled in Ubuntu 18.04 and the version available in the software center hasn't been updated for years.

So is there a way to install the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the latest from the Cantarell github page, and build it from source:
https://github.com/madig/cantarell-fonts/releases

The latest release is 0.101 from Mar 15 2018.

Build and install are very simple:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip meson ninja-build
pip3 install --user fontmake
pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/psautohint.git@v1.1.0#egg=psautohint
meson build
cd build
sudo ninja install
```

Result:

```
Installing appstream/org.gnome.cantarell.metainfo.xml to /usr/local/share/metainfo/org.gnome.cantarell.metainfo.xml
Installing /home/valiano/cantarell-fonts-0.101/prebuilt/Cantarell-Thin.otf to /usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell
Installing /home/valiano/cantarell-fonts-0.101/prebuilt/Cantarell-Light.otf to /usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell
Installing /home/valiano/cantarell-fonts-0.101/prebuilt/Cantarell-Regular.otf to /usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell
Installing /home/valiano/cantarell-fonts-0.101/prebuilt/Cantarell-Bold.otf to /usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell
Installing /home/valiano/cantarell-fonts-0.101/prebuilt/Cantarell-ExtraBold.otf to /usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell
```